Unable to create external table in Hive Metastore with a Unity Catalog enabled Shared Cluster
I have a shared cluster that is unity catalog enabled. I am able to do a:  
select * from hive_metastore.clean.table_name  but when i try to create a table
%sql CREATE TABLE hive_metastore.clean.dummy_new (
Name STRING,
Age LONG
)
USING DELTA
LOCATION 'abfss://container@storageaccount.dfs.core.windows.net/path'
I get a SparkSecurityException: [INSUFFICIENT_PERMISSIONS] Insufficient privileges:
User does not have permission SELECT on any file. error.
With a sinlge user cluster i am able to create a table inside a hive metastore, same command no errors.
Upon reading documentation mentioned here  it says
Because compute resources that use shared access mode are enabled for legacy table access control by default, that means that if you use that access mode, you must have table access control privileges on the Hive metastore that you are migrating from. You can grant yourself access using the following SQL command:
GRANT all_privileges ON catalog hive_metastore TO `<user>`

Following this gives this error: AnalysisException: Action Unknown ActionType ALL_PRIVILEGES cannot be granted on CATALOG
Is the documentation wrong? Upon cross checking with my admin my user does have all the rights as shown below:

Will appreciate any help: the main goal is to be able to Use Hive Metastore without any problems while enabling Unity Catalog.


[INSUFFICIENT_PERMISSIONS] Insufficient privileges: User does not have
permission SELECT on any file. error.

Regarding the above error, you accurately noted the limitations mentioned. However, when using Unity Catalog with shared clusters, you need to approach things differently. Unity Catalog, combined with shared clusters, offers excellent user isolation, ensuring data access is properly controlled. Unlike DBFS, which lacks any access control, and ADLS, which only provides file-level access control, Unity Catalog ensures users can't access data without the proper permissions.
You can follow the approach below:
To access data on ADLS using the abfss protocol, you need to create external locations and assign the appropriate permissions to your users.
An external location combines a cloud storage path with a storage credential that authorizes access to that path. Each external location is subject to Unity Catalog access-control policies, which determine which users and groups can access the credential. If a user lacks access to an external location in Unity Catalog, the request will fail, and Unity Catalog will not attempt to authenticate to your cloud tenant on the user's behalf. Only users who need to create external tables, external volumes, or managed storage locations should be granted permission to create and use external locations. Learn more about creating an external location to connect cloud storage to Azure Databricks.
Learn more about Create an external location to connect cloud storage to Azure Databricks.
Note: While Unity Catalog supports path-based access to external tables and external volumes using cloud storage URIs, Databricks recommends that users read and write all Unity Catalog tables using table names and access data in volumes using /Volumes paths.
Reference: SO Link

Hi, Thanks for proposing a solution @DileeprajnarayanThumula But as i already mentioned i am able to access the data when using single user cluster. An external location is already created and the required permissions are already assigned.

@LavMehta Can you confirm if the  Table Access Control is not enabled on this cluster.

It is enabled. I reached out to databricks and now the documentation is updated- Instead of all_privileges  GRANT all privileges ON catalog hive_metastore TO <user> is the correct way. My admin granted me this privilege and still i am facing the same issue.
